# Same size SVGs not same size once on the page?

Tags: html, css, svg

Working on this site for a school project, Heres the site in question:
http://jmtestserver.net46.net/

As you can see the boxes on the right stick down further because of the images sizes being off.  If you inspect the element, the working ones say 126x71 and the ones that are too big say 126x127 and I have no idea where the size difference is coming from.

I resized the images based on the working ones in illustrator like this gfy shows:

http://gfycat.com/ChillyFlawlessDrever

I dont know how to check the size of a SVG offline because I can only open it in illustrator but it appears to be the exact same size to me in illustrator but when I insert it in the web page it "grows" for some reason I have no clue despite it having the exact same CSS.

Any help would be appreciated, because I am getting caught up on very small stuff.

I guess: How can I check the size of an SVG offline, and what would cause it to "grow" like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
photo_icon {
  /* remove margin top */
  height: 75px;
}
```

and make sure the canvas is the same for each AI file.

[image]

**long answer**

- Use classes instead of ids. Create a single class called `box` to control your boxes.
- Make a single canvas in Illustrator, and use the same canvas to export your svgs
- Give your boxes a `min-height` depending on the highest box
- Or use flexbox for equal height boxes

Extra space does come from the canvas size:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at my new screenshot, see if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok totally makes sense thank you I got it working!  I thought this is what I was doing earlier, but starting over from a blank canvas and adjusting the canvas did the trick!  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I usually use http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/stable/editor/svg-editor.html

Or you can edit viewport and viewbox value manualy. But you don't need.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html

Comment: I prefer have all image in the same size... if not you can´t reuse easily

Comment: That is what I don't get is they are all the same size.  I even just remade them all on the exact same canvas.  It is only when I put them in the webpage that they get different.  Also I can't get my SVG to load in that editor, it just gets stuck on "loading".

Comment: here is a zip of my icons if you have any way to confirm that they are same size... https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk83qjc6hvxw8l8/camera_icon.zip?dl=0

Comment: I open the files and they are differents the viewBox are different.

 viewBox="0 0 82.8 66.2"  viewBox="0 0 100 100"

Comment: Well I matched them up by height because some were wider but I only needed the height to match up - could that be why?

Comment: The best option is open with 
http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/stable/editor/svg-editor.html

Now you can edit the height and width in the SVG code options (look like HTML :)

Probably the editor removes the viewBox, this happened to me with your files.

You can change the height and width, use the same for all pictures.